# Page not found after submitting form django

Tags: python, django

I have a comment model in my forum and when I try to submit it it says:

```
 "Page not found - /POST?csrfmiddlewaretoken".
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def comment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment.post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
            comment.writer = request.user
            comment = form.save()
            messages.info(request, 'comment published')
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Thank you for your comment'}, safe=False)
    else:
        form = CommentCreationForm()
```

html file:

```
<form action="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.text.errors }}
   <label for="{{ form.text.id_for_label }}">comment:</label>
   {{ form.text }}
   <button id="comment" type="submit">comment</button>
</form>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
path('<int:pk>/comment/', views.comment, name='comment'),
```

By the way, can you help me make it in ajax?

Comment: Can you show `urls.py`? And also useful, full traceback.

Comment: @NKSM path('<int:pk>/comment/', views.comment, name='comment'),

Comment: It seems like you are also getting an error in your method view. You have to add **post**  and **user** before `save()` like: `form.instance.post=post` and `form.instance.writer=user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add **url** to the attribute **action** and `POST` to **method** attribute:

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' post.pk %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.text.errors }}
   <label for="{{ form.text.id_for_label }}">comment:</label>
   {{ form.text }}
   <button id="comment" type="submit">comment</button>
</form>
```

Also provide **`post.pk`** in `{% url 'comment' post.pk %}`.